# c++ modules include issues w clang++17

Tags: c++, module, clang, clang++, c++-modules

With the new Clang++, what I'm noticing is you cant implement a simple lambda without having to resort to random hacks to get the compiler to not delete default constructors.  I posted a simple project based on the work of a Clang contributor of an A B module test (so everything minus this lambda store implemented).  That code works fine but it merely returns an int from a module.

clang version 17.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project f66b9fe5876d670b38351c9a7efd90e793f35a30)

can't try on g++ (13 built from master) either because it doesnt have aarch64 on mac. hope i am missing something in the switch that might allow me to compile and use generics?

a.cppm

```
module;

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <new>
#include <memory>

export module a;

export template<typename T>
class func;

export template<typename R, typename... Args>
class func<R(Args...)> {
public:
    func() { };

    template<typename F>
    func(F&& func) : impl_(new Impl<typename std::decay<F>::type>(std::forward<F>(func))) {}

    R operator()(Args... args) const {
        if (impl_)
            return impl_->call(args...);
        throw std::runtime_error("Empty func object");
    }

    explicit operator bool() const {
        return static_cast<bool>(impl_);
    }

private:
    struct Base {
        virtual ~Base() { };
        virtual R call(Args... args) const = 0;
    };

    template<typename F>
    struct Impl : Base {
        explicit Impl(F&& func) : func_(std::forward<F>(func)) {}

        R call(Args... args) const override {
            return func_(args...);
        }

        F func_;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Base> impl_ = nullptr;
};

// ** does NOT compile with this line commented:
// ** abc2 is unused, not exported.
// func<void()> abc2 = func<void()>([]() -> void { });

export int foo() {
    return 43;
}
```

b.cppm:

```
export module b;
import a;
export int bar() {
    return 43;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(two_libraries CXX C ASM)

set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "2182bf5c-ef0d-489a-91da-49dbc3090d2a")

include(../cxx_modules_rules_clang.cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_library(a STATIC)
target_sources(a
  PUBLIC
    FILE_SET cxx_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES
    a.cppm
)

add_library(b STATIC)
target_sources(b
  PUBLIC
    FILE_SET cxx_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES
    b.cppm
)

# The compiler won't find module 'a' if we delete the following line.
target_link_libraries(b PUBLIC a)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC a b)
```

main.cpp:

```
import a;
import b;

int main() {
    foo();
    bar();

    func<void()> abc3 = func<void()>([]() -> void { });
    abc3();
    
    return 0;
}
```

build log with abc2 commented out:

```
kalen@Kalens-Mac-mini build % ninja                     
[8/10] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o 
/Users/kalen/Dropbox/src/llvm-project/build/bin/clang++   -std=c++20 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d @CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.modmap -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/kalen/src/CMake-Modules-Examples/two_static_libraries/main.cpp
In file included from /Users/kalen/src/CMake-Modules-Examples/two_static_libraries/main.cpp:2:
/Users/kalen/src/CMake-Modules-Examples/two_static_libraries/a.cppm:20:22: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::unique_ptr<Base>'
    func(F&& func) : impl_(new Impl<typename std::decay<F>::type>(std::forward<F>(func))) {}
                     ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kalen/src/CMake-Modules-Examples/two_static_libraries/main.cpp:9:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func<void ()>::func<(lambda at /Users/kalen/src/CMake-Modules-Examples/two_static_libraries/main.cpp:9:38)>' requested here
    func<void()> abc3 = func<void()>([]() -> void { });
                        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:121:59: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'Impl<typename std::decay<(lambda at /Users/kalen/src/CMake-Modules-Examples/two_static_libraries/main.cpp:9:38)>::type> *' (aka 'Impl<(lambda at /Users/kalen/src/CMake-Modules-Examples/two_static_libraries/main.cpp:9:38)> *') to 'const unique_ptr<Base>' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_UNIQUE_PTR_TRIVIAL_ABI _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS unique_ptr {
                                                          ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:185:21: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_default_constructible<std::default_delete<func<void ()>::Base>>::value' was not satisfied [with _Dummy = true]
  _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_(pointer(), __default_init_tag()) {}
                    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:190:12: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_default_constructible<std::default_delete<func<void ()>::Base>>::value' was not satisfied [with _Dummy = true]
  explicit unique_ptr(pointer __p) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_(__p, __default_init_tag()) {}
           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:222:3: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>' against 'Impl<typename std::decay<(lambda at /Users/kalen/src/CMake-Modules-Examples/two_static_libraries/main.cpp:9:38)>::type> *' (aka 'Impl<(lambda at /Users/kalen/src/CMake-Modules-Examples/two_static_libraries/main.cpp:9:38)> *')
  unique_ptr(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) _NOEXCEPT
  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:180:21: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
  _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr() _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_(pointer(), __default_init_tag()) {}
                    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:195:3: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  unique_ptr(pointer __p, _LValRefType<_Dummy> __d) _NOEXCEPT
  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:201:3: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  unique_ptr(pointer __p, _GoodRValRefType<_Dummy> __d) _NOEXCEPT
  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:210:3: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
```

when abc2 is NOT commented, it works.  so if you dont instance the type in module it doesn't work for any users of the module.  its like it tree shakes without knowing its use outside of the module.  i do wonder if i can mitigate with a switch?

as-is this leads me to believe the latest clang++ is broken, v17 i built around mar 28th.  am reporting this there too incase its not something i am missing switch-wise or something?